# default template argument and parameter pack

Tags: c++, parameter-pack, default-template-argument

In a classic recursive template specialization I need one type multiple times in the class definition, e.g. for inheriting and using statement, maybe on other places also.

Example:

```
 template < typename ... T > 
class C;

template < typename FIRST, typename ... REST>
class C< FIRST, REST...>: public std::conditional_t< sizeof...(REST), C<REST...>, Empty >
{
    public:
    using std::conditional_t< sizeof...(REST), C<REST...>, Empty >::Set;
    void Set( FIRST );
};
```

As you can see, I need to write multiple times the `std::conditional_t< sizeof...(REST), C<REST...>, Empty >` expression.

The problem is, that I can`t either use

```
template < typename ... T >
class C;

template < typename FIRST, typename ... REST, typename INHERIT = std::conditional_t< sizeof...(REST), C<REST...>, Empty >>
class C< FIRST, REST...>: public INHERIT
{
    using INHERIT::Set;
};
```

fails because C++ did not allow default template parameters in specializations

nor

```
template < typename ... T, typename INHERIT = std::conditional_t< sizeof...(REST), C<REST...>, Empty >  >
class C;

...
```

fails because I can not use default template arguments behind a parameter pack. Even if this would be allowed, class C is not defined yet and as this `C<REST...>` will fail also.

Is there any trick to avoid to multiple define the `std::conditional_t< sizeof...(REST), C<REST...>, Empty >` statement?

Answer (score 3):

You could shorten the duplication down slightly by creating an alias template, here called `mybase`:

```
template <class... REST>
using mybase = std::conditional_t<sizeof...(REST), C<REST...>, Empty>;

template <typename FIRST, typename... REST>
class C<FIRST, REST...> : public mybase<REST...> {
public:
    using mybase<REST...>::Set;
    void Set(FIRST);
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Good catch! But on my real world code the parameter list is slightly longer... any suggestions?

Comment: @Klaus I think I would have to see it before I give it a try. :-)